# Is @Before and @AfterReturning combination possible?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I have a method that will update a field, but I want to check the value before that method is executed, so I can determine the action (edit/add/delete).

```
@Before(value = "execution(* com.test.app.*.service.DefaultBirthRegistrationService.updateRegistrationField(..)) && args(referenceNumber, fieldDetails)")
    public void assignAction(String referenceNumber, BirthRegistrationField fieldDetails) {
        Action action = birthRegistrationService.determineUpdateAction(referenceNumber, fieldDetails, Action.EDITED);
    }
```

Then after the `updateRegistrationField()` method is succesfully executed I want to log the event, but **with** the value of `action` that is set in `@Before`. I do **not** want to log the event in case `updateRegistrationField()` fails. That is why I want to use `@AfterReturning.` This is the code of `@AfterReturning`:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.test.app.*.service.DefaultBirthRegistrationService.updateRegistrationField(..)) && args(referenceNumber, fieldDetails)")
    public void editEvent(String referenceNumber, BirthRegistrationField fieldDetails) {
        audit(referenceNumber, action, fieldDetails.getName());
    }
```

The variable `action`, should be the value assigned in `@Before`.

Is this possible?

I have also looked at using `@Around` but the problem is that I only want to execute a part of the code **before** executing the method, and a part of the code **after** executing the method.

Comment: `@Around` is exactly what you should be using . Could you please elaborate why `@Around` does not work for you ?

Comment: Just use an around aspect. Execute the before part, then call proceed, then do your after returning path. If it fails the latter won't execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `DefaultBirthRegistrationService.updateRegistrationField()` throws exception when the operation fails , following code should work in your case.

```java
@Around(value = "execution(* com.test.app.*.service.DefaultBirthRegistrationService.updateRegistrationField(..)) && args(referenceNumber, fieldDetails)")
public Object assignActionAndAuditEvent(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,String referenceNumber, BirthRegistrationField fieldDetails) throws Throwable {
    Action action = birthRegistrationService.determineUpdateAction(referenceNumber, fieldDetails, Action.EDITED);
    Object res = joinPoint.proceed();
    audit(referenceNumber, action, fieldDetails.getName());     
    return res;
}
```